# MVC 4 - onClick replace .js file with another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

NET.

I am developing prototype in .NET and in dashboard I have **8** different categories. Each catogory has unique `.js` file.

**For eg:** If I click on Banking category link ( from `~/Views/Home/IndustryDashboard` view ), my `~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`(this file has all the `.js` files included) file should replace the `default.js` with `banking.js` file

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#gt-industry-1').on('click', function () {
        loadJS = function (src) {
            var oldFile = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/default.js'>");
            var newFile = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/banking.js'>");
            oldFile.replaceWith(newFile);
        };
        loadJS("~/Scripts/banking.js");
    });
});
```

**Ref Images:**

[image]

[image]

**Any help please?**

Comment: you should use server side conditional if else statements that renders javascript based on page you render ,

Comment: Hi **@vishal sharma**, I am very new to this technology, can you please explain a bit / demo code please?

Comment: like this , @if (pagedetectionLogic)
    {
        @Scripts.Render("scripturl")
    }else if(otherpage) {
           @Scripts.Render("scripturl")    }

Comment: I believe its not a single page application and page refreshes when url clicks, right ?

Comment: Yes Vishal... it has almost 150+ files :(

Comment: Why are you even considering this? Just bundle all the 8 scripts so they are minimized and cached and put in your view.

Comment: I have category based content in all .js files... Eg: banking.js, travel.js etc...

Comment: 150+ files , you can do some sort of naming conventions when loading scripts, so if your action will be "Banking" then js file to load will be banking.js , will that work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah!

I made it worked like below :)

Updated the code in `HomeController.cs` as below

```
public ActionResult Dashboard() {
  Session["tempval"] = at.ToString();
  ViewBag.str = at;
  return View();
}
```

And `_Layout.cshtml` file, code as follows...

```
@if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempval"]) == 1) {
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/industry_init-b2b.js")"></script>
}

else if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempval"]) == 2) {
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/industry_init-banking.js")"></script>
}

else {
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/init-default.js")"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you handle it in the view itself.
Place Common Files in _Layout.cshtml File.
And the page based js File should be added in the View itself.